# Django sqlite Database

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite, django-models

This is my query set

```
qs = Pret.objects.values('brand').annotate(dcount = Count('brand')).annotate(avg = Avg('price'))
```

these are the responses
for qs[0]

```
{'brand': 1, 'dcount': 26, 'avg': 2197.0}
```

and I want that instead of brand:1, I get the brand names in all these records in qs. It's a foreign key concept, but I am unable to understand this in Django database. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Assuming the brand name is stored in a field called `name` on the Brand model, try `Pret.objects.values('brand__name')...`

Comment: dear this worked :)

Comment: Thankyou so much